# How to proper inherit values into thread class with wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a wxPython gui that is controlling some hardware.
I need a button to disable while a function is running. The function also receives an argument value

let's say that I have this function that is bound to a button press:

```
    def button_press(self, event):

       in_val = self.num_in.GetValue() #grabs a value from a NumCtrl
       TheThread(in_val) #initiates the thread with argument
       btn = event.GetEventObject() 
       btn.Disable() #disables button
```

this function goes to the following thread class:

```
    class TheThread(Thread):
def __init__(self, in_val):

    """Init Worker Thread Class."""
    Thread.__init__(self)

    self.run(in_val)

def run(self, in_val):
    print val
    time.sleep(5)

    wx.CallAfter(Publisher.sendMessage, "ctrl")
    """
    threadsafe method to call a pub.subscribe that runs a 
    function to re-enable button
    """
```

This works improperly, as the gui freezes during the function run period, and the button does not properly disable.

How do I properly inherit this argument to allow this to run properly?
Maybe something involving self.start() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in your guess about the `start` method.

`run` is the method that gets invoked on the new thread, and `start` is the method you want to call to tell the `Thread` object to do that.

In your example, by calling `run` yourself you're calling `run` on the main thread and no threading is taking place at all. (the thread is never started)

```
class TheThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, in_val):

        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.in_val = in_val
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        print self.in_val
        time.sleep(5)

        wx.CallAfter(Publisher.sendMessage, "ctrl")
        """
        threadsafe method to call a pub.subscribe that runs a 
        function to re-enable button
        """
```

Comment: Thank you! So I guess in the case of threading, you don't pass the argument value through to the next function, but instead pass it as a self.var to the function? is there a reason for this?

Comment: @supremus_58 right, the `run` method doesn't take any arguments itself. However if you pass a target function instead you can provide arguments as well, and the default `Thread.run` method will invoke the target callable with the arguments you provide. `t = Thread(target=my_func, args=("arg1", "arg2"), kwargs={"kwarg1":"val"})` `t.start()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `run()` from `__init__()`. `run()` sleeps for 5 seconds and then returns. But `__init__()` needs to return before the object is fully instantiated, and the calling code blocks until `__init__()` returns. It is the same situation for most function calls, i.e. the calling code waits for the function to return (or yield in the case of a generator) before continuing execution.

To correct this problem remove the call to run() from `__init__()` and call the `start()` method on the `TheThread()` instance:

```
def button_press(self, event):
    in_val = self.num_in.GetValue()
    TheThread(in_val).start()
    btn = event.GetEventObject() 
    btn.Disable() #disables button

class TheThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, in_val):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        super(TheThread, self).__init__()
        self.in_val = in_val

    def run(self):
        print self.in_val
        time.sleep(5)
        wx.CallAfter(Publisher.sendMessage, "ctrl")
```

You could also call the thread's `start()` method within `__init__()`, however, the more common way is to call start on the thread instance itself. This is a more flexible solution because the thread can be created first and then started later, e.g. if you had a pool of threads in which all threads are created first and then started together.